# Wireless network lost internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I'm working on a network with 6 workstations, server, Netgear 16 port switch, Netgear Router R6250 and it has been chugging along for well over a year now. Yesterday, none of the wireless devices can connect to the internet. They can see all of the SSIDs and connect to any of the networks and get an IP stack via DHCP but none of them can get to the internet. All of the wired computers can connect just fine but the wired devices can't surf the web.

On a laptop, I can go to the command line, run ipconfig and it shows a valid IP. I can ping the router but I can't get past that. I tried a tracert but it hangs and times out for any address.

On the Netgear R6250, I have updated the firmware, verified all of the settings and can see all of the devices connecting to it, both wired and wireless. I have rebooted the router but nothing seems to have worked for the wireless devices. I am pretty sure that nothing has changed on the router as I'm the only one with admin access to the device and I haven't been on it in more than 6 months. Has the wireless side of the router just taken a dirt nap? I'm really open for suggestions on this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be a problem with your ISP? :)

Comment: If it was the ISP, I would think that the desktops would have a problem as well but they don't. All devices go through the same router and then out so I would not expect the ISP to know which to block.

Comment: You can try this; remove or turn off the wireless network in the router admin, save the settings, power off the router then restart it, re-establish the wireless network. If it still doesn't work, it is likely the wireless functionality of the router has died.